# select from two tables and group by a common column date in both tables

Tags: mysql

Guys I looked for a solution but could not get it for my problem
I will be grateful if anyone could help
I have three tables `term1`,`term2`,`term3` which have identical columns 
`Adm`,`date`, `amountneeded`,`amountpaid`,
The date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`
I need to retrieve the `total amountpaid` from the three tables and `group` it by `year`

The result should be

```
year    total
2012    323000
2013    423000
```

---

Comment: Nice requirement. Anything else you want us to do?

Comment: provide some sample data.

Comment: http://gohiresomeonetodoyourhomework.com   , This is not a place were people can put their homowork on and without any input of theirselfs get the code. And if you get it your lucky because not many people do that

Comment: i was googling the whole day but could not find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select tyear,sum(total) from ( select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as tyear ,sum(amountpaid) as total from term1 group by tyear union all select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as tyear ,sum(amountpaid) as total from term2 group by tyear union all select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as tyear ,sum(amountpaid) as total from term1 group by tyear )a group by tyear

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
select tyear,sum(total)
from (
      select DATEPART(yyyy,date) as tyear ,sum(amountpaid) as total
      from  term1
      group by DATEPART(yyyy,date)
      union all
      select  DATEPART(yyyy,date) as tyear ,sum(amountpaid) as total
      from  term2
      group by DATEPART(yyyy,date)
      union all
      select  DATEPART(yyyy,date) as tyear ,sum(amountpaid) as total
      from  term1
      group by DATEPART(yyyy,date)
   )a group by tyear
```

Comment: hi mukesh the above query gives me the following error
#1305 - FUNCTION fees.datepart does not exist

Comment: still  gives me the same errror
#1305 - FUNCTION fees.DATEPART does not exist

Comment: fees is my database name

Comment: thanks mukesh
i got the answer, i changed the datepart to extract
below is the answer